# Nine objects in non-empty boxes

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

In how many ways 9 identical objects can be put in non-empty boxes of arbitrary size?

Is solution integer partition of 9? That is 30?

Comment: Are the boxes distinguishable?  That is, is putting eight in the first box an one in the second different from putting one in the first and eight in the second?

Comment: The boxes are not distinguishable.

Comment: Then it's partitions, as you said.  (I haven't checked that the answer is $30$.)

Comment: Putting eight in the first box an one in the second is the same as putting one in the first and eight in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are talking about partitions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

In your case, they are

9

8-1

7-2

7-1-1

6-3

6-2-1

6-1-1-1

5-4

5-3-1

5-2-2

5-2-1-1

5-1-1-1-1

4-4-1

4-3-2

4-3-1-1

4-2-2-1

4-2-1-1-1

4-1-1-1-1-1

3-3-3

3-3-2-1

3-3-1-1-1

3-2-2-2

3-2-2-1-1

3-2-1-1-1-1

3-1-1-1-1-1-1

2-2-2-2-1

2-2-2-1-1-1

2-2-1-1-1-1-1

2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1

1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the boxes are distinguishable, we can put **up to** 8 bars between 9 objects, each bar separating two boxes. There are 2^8 ways to set the bars, 2 meaning a bar is either there or not. So the answer is 256.

Assuming the boxes are indistinguishable, the question becomes sum of number seperation. There are 1 one to use only 1 box, 8 ways to use 2 boxes, 7 ways to use 3 boxes (711,621,531,522,441,432,333), etc.

Comment: The boxes are indistinguishable. But, there is only 4 ways to use 2 boxes: 81, 72, 63, 54. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oops, typo, 8 should be 4. See my counting with case of 3 boxes - same idea.